# Failover Cluster Manager showing wrong interface for node

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v, failover, windows-cluster

I have a 2 node 2012 R2 Hyper-V setup that i am trying to configure Hyper-V HA. The network setup for both nodes are as follows:

**Total:** (8 x Ports):

4 x Adapters - (Teamed:Production/VM external access) @ 3 x 1Gbps and 1 x 10Gbps

**Teaming Mode:** Switch Independent

**Load balancing mode**: Dynamic

**Stanby adapter:** None (All adapters active)

**Network:** 192.168.100.x

2 x Adapters - iSCSI (MPIO) @ 10Gbps

**Network:** 192.168.115.x

1 x Adapters - Cluster (Managment,VM Migration and replication) @ 10Gbps

**Network:** 192.168.100.x

1 x Adapters - Phone Network @ 1Gbps

**Network:** 192.168.104.x

The problem is that the failover and cluster manager (FCM) is selecting the Production network for one node and the cluster for the other. I want the cluster network to be dedicated for managing the hyper-v, migrations and replication.

I have configured the adapter order on the nodes as follows:

vEthernet (vSwitch_Production)

Team_Production

NIC1 - Production

NIC2 - Production

NIC3 - Production

NIC4 - Production

NIC5 - Cluster

NIC6 - iSCSI

NIC7 - iSCSI

NIC8 - Phone

Can anyone please comment as to if this network setup will work with Hyper-V HA and, how I can ensure the correct adapters are selected by FCM?

Answer (score 4):

Launch FCM, specify a required cluster and go **Networks**. Then select the network you want to modify settings for and click **Properties**. This way you can allow or forbid cluster/client communication on certain networks. You can also manually configure live migration channels over there.

More recommendations on how to isolate network traffic on Hyper-V cluster can be found here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn550728(v=ws.11).aspx

As for your projected network design, it looks reasonable to me. But still refer to this article to learn more about different approaches to networking setup on Failover Cluster with Hyper-V: http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN268062/EN

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this issue is not isolating the traffic type its the fact that FCM is detecting the wrong adapter in the network section.

Comment: Try to segregate your production and cluster networks by using different subnets. AFAIK Failover Clustering can recognize only one IP address per subnet, so it ignores all of the rest. This is a good practise, especially if you want to have that networks dedicated to specific traffic type.

Comment: I did consider breaking the IP scopes to differnt subnets however does anyone know how FCM choose which IP per subnet. This is the key point of my question, if I could get the answer to that I could be up and running.